# css3 animations using "natural" property value

Tags: css, animation

I would like to define a CSS3 animation which, at some points during the animation, uses the natural value for a property as if the animation was not applied.

e.g.

```
@keyframes fadeblue
{
  0%
  {
    background-color: natural;
  }
  100% 
  {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}    
.thing1
{
  background-color: red;
  animation: fadeblue 2s;
}
.thing2
{
  background-color: green;
  animation: fadeblue 2s;
}
```

thing1 would fade from red to blue while thing2 would fade from green to blue.
What value should I use in the place of `natural` in the 0% keyframe?

I have tried both inherit and transparent but neither had the desired effect.

N.B. I know this can be done with a JavaScript solution but if possible I'd prefer a pure css3 solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems you can't reference the original colour in keyframes. However, you can just specify [one keyframe](http://lea.verou.me/2012/12/animations-with-one-keyframe/) in a `keyframes` declaration and let the browser interpolate the colors for you. Using a keyframe of just `50%` will use the original properties at `0%` (aka `from`) and `100%` (aka `to`).

With this knowledge we can also effectively queue animations using `animation-delay` to create what looks like a single animation, but isn't.

For example:

```css
@keyframes fadeblue {
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
@keyframes fadewhite {
  50% {
    background-color: white;
  }
}   
.thing1 {
  background-color: red;
  animation: fadeblue 2s,
             fadewhite 2s 2s; 
             /* shorthand here is: animation-name animation-duration animation-delay */
}
.thing2 {
  background-color: green;
  animation: fadeblue 2s,
             fadewhite 2s 2s;
}
.thing3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  animation: fadeblue 2s,
             fadewhite 2s 2s;
}
.thing4 {
  background-color: purple;
  animation: fadeblue 2s,
             fadewhite 2s 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="thing1">Thing 1</div>
<div class="thing2">Thing 2</div>
<div class="thing3">Thing 2</div>
<div class="thing4">Thing 2</div>
```

You'll see the elements fade to blue and back to the original colour, then fade to white then the original colour.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ty6s1yzc/) for good measure.

Comment: aha.
ok this solves the specific scenario in the question but not other cases (such as where the natural colour  should be used part way through the animation, not just at the start)

Comment: @DJL consider the solution with pseudo-elements I've presented in other answer. You do have more flexibility with keyframes there.

Comment: Fair comment @DJL.
I've adjusted the answer to hopefully give a full solution

Comment: An interesting idea. Feels a little hacky but does indeed get the job done.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this if you use a pseudo-element (e.g. `:before`) for `.thing1` and `. thing2`, set it's color to blue, and animate it's `opacity`. It's a bit more work, but I believe it will be more flexible solution:

*(see working demo below)*

```css
@keyframes fadeblue {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.thing1,
.thing2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.thing1:before,
.thing2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  animation: fadeblue 2s infinite;
}
.thing1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.thing2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="thing1"></div>
<div class="thing2"></div>
```

Comment: This could be a handy approach if the before and after pseudo elements are not already used for something